# In what format Cursor of ContentResolver retruns contacts saved on the device?

Tags: android, phone-number, mobile-country-code

I am  fetching the contacts saved on the device using following code

```
     String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
Cursor cur = mParentActivity.getContentResolver().
                   query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                           null, null, null, sortOrder);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    String phoneNo = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }
```

I am using my Huawei phone to test this and getting local contacts like

```
+61 455 553 970

+972 55-644-4862
```

My question is,  will i get space after the country telephone code for all the devices ?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

NUMBER
public static final String NUMBER
The phone number as the user entered it.

Type: TEXT

So it seems that it will be like it was provided. I doubt that you can assume that it will always have space after country code. 
You can check NORMALIZED_NUMBER. It may be better for your use case.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#NUMBER

Edit: 
You can use https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber to validate phone number.